# Best way to add an abstract class for which two classes extend it?

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

I have two methods which write text to a text file. Both methods are pretty much identical apart from the `filepath` they write to. Here is my code for both of them.

```
public class WriteFileTeacher {
  private String filename="/mylocation/teachers.txt";
  public void writeToFileTeacher (String course) {
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
      out.println(course);// this is what gets saved
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}


public class WriteFileCourse {
  private String filename="/mylocation/courses.txt";
  public void writeToFileCourse (String course) {
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
      out.println(course);// this is what gets saved
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Since both methods are pretty much identical apart from the path name, I was looking for a suggestion on how to write an abstract class, that both of these classes could extend?

Comment: You should just pass `filename` as a parameter. No need to create an object for what can easily be a one-off operation.

Comment: inheritance in your case is overkill, just write a Util class and have a static method which takes a path and content and write that content in that file specified in path.

Comment: @Eric in Java an abstract class does contain logic. It sounds like you have abstract classes confused with interfaces.

Comment: Or just use the utility method of the JDK doing that for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-

Comment: im so so sorry please see my edit . My second method should have said "writeToFileCourse"

Comment: @MarkB yup, 3 years of c++ and sleepless nights will do that to ya... (I deleted that comment)

Comment: @BigAl1992, why does it have to be named as `writeToFileCourse`? That's a bad practice in your case

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FileWriter {
    private final String fileName;

    public FileWriter(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void writeToFile() {
        // your source is this.fileName
    }
}
```

You needn't a class hierarchy in this case due to the sameness of the `writeToFileTeacher` methods. Just make a constructor that takes a file name as a parameter and means where your writer should write to.

That is a common class to writing to a file, don't worry about method naming, it simply can be named `writeToFile`.

Comment: Yes exactly. He could just pass in the parameter and then all would be done

Comment: [Don't write objects that end with -ER](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/03/09/objects-end-with-er.html)

Comment: @JanezKuhar, Oracle doesn't see anything bad with such naming ([`Raster` as an example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html))

Answer (score 0):

The filename value may be a private information from concrete subclasses.

 So, using a parameter to transmit this information can be undesirable.

Why not put in common this two methods since they do the same thing ? 
You can factor the common processing in a private method.

```
public class WriteFileService {
  private String fileTeachers="/mylocation/teachers.txt";
  private String fileCourses="/mylocation/courses.txt";

  public void writeToFileTeacher (String course) {
    writeToFileCommon(course, fileTeachers);
  }

 public void writeToFileCourse(String course) {
    writeToFileCommon(course, fileCourses);
  }

 private void writeToFileCommon(String course, String file) {
  try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
      out.println(course);// this is what gets saved
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }        
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach may be something like that:

```
public class MyAbstractWriterClass {

    protected abstract String getFilePath();

    public void writeToFileTeacher(String course){
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(getFilePath(), true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
            out.println(course);// this is what gets saved
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Or you may create a class to write to any file just passing the String content and passing this writer class as a parameter to yout main class (like the strategy pattern):

```
class GenericFileWriter {
    private final filePath;
    GenericFileWriter(String file) {
        this.filePath = file;
    }
    public void write(String content) {
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(this.filePath, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
            out.println(course);// this is what gets saved
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```